# How do I return a set of rows when a condition is true on one or more rows within the set?

Tags: sql

How do I return a set of multiple rows when a condition is true on one or more rows within the set?

```
RECORD  VERSION INDICATOR AREA
1234    01  A     CA
1234    02  B     CA
1234    03  C     CA
5678    01  D     CO
5678    02  L     CO
5678    03  F     CO
```

For example, I would like to return all rows within a record set if a B indicator is present within the set.

I can query for that condition, but it simply returns the one row where the condition is true.

```
SELECT
record,
version,
indicator, 
area

FROM vista
WHERE indicator = 'B';
```

Expected results:

```
RECORD  VERSION INDICATOR AREA
1234    01  A     CA
1234    02  B     CA
1234    03  C     CA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that checks for a record with a `'B'` indicator.

```
SELECT v1.record,
       v1.version,
       v1.indicator, 
       v1.area
       FROM vista v1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM vista v2
                            WHERE v2.record = v1.record
                                  AND v2.indicator = 'B');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the common field is `Area`, you want two subsets that match on that field.

```sql
SELECT va.record, va.version, va.indicator, va.area
FROM vista va
WHERE va.Area = 'CA' AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM vista WHERE Area = va.Area and vi.indicator = 'B'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select record, version, indicator, area
from vista
where area IN
 (
 select area
 from vista
 where indicator = "B"
 )
```

Comment: This will generally fail with a "subquery returned more than one row" error.

Comment: I changed = to IN to address your concern.